# regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey there how do I escape `'` and `"` using javascript regex?

because I want

```
Annie said, "It's really funny."
```

to be like,

```
Annie said, \"It\'s really funny.\"
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I hope the OP isn't trying to escape user input on the client side.

Comment: no I dont. it's gonna be on the server side. I am working in node. so don't ya woory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.replace`.

```
string.replace(/(['"])/g, "\\$1")
```

**Example:**

```
> var s = 'Annie said, "It\'s really funny."'
undefined
> console.log(s.replace(/(['"])/g, "\\$1"))
Annie said, \"It\'s really funny.\"
```

Comment: you guys are so awesome. @hwnd and avinash-raj
I want to ask a question, which is better and more efficient in order to get this done, use 2 replace for ' and " or just use this regex?

Comment: @user2558534 use a one.

Comment: You the one says, `Hey there how do I escape ' and " using javascript regex?`